# Minimal prime of a ring is contraction of some prime ideal of any extension of the ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

Let $S$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and let $R$ be any subring of $S.$ Let $p$ be a minimal prime of $R.$ Then how can I show that there is a prime ideal $q$ of $S$ whose contraction is $p,$ i.e., $q \cap R = p.$

What I am trying to show is the  necessary and sufficient condition that $p=p^{ec}.$ Clearly $p \subset p^{ec}.$ But the other way I couldn't complete. I need some help.

Comment: Regarding the notation $p=p^{ec}$, I suspect you have in mind taking the *extension* of ideal $p\subset R$ to $S$ (finite sums of products of elements from $p$ times elements of $S$), followed by the contraction of that ideal (not necessarily a prime in $S$ even when $p$ is prime in $R$) back to $R$ by intersection, hence $(p^e)^c$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Hint. Pick a prime ideal in the ring of fractions $(R\setminus p)^{-1}S$.

Comment: Yes that helps, follows from the immediate commutative diagram.